# How can I add jars to the classpath when I invoke Jython *without* adding them to $CLASSPATH?

Tags: classpath, jython, jar

I'd like to do something similar to `jython -cp FOO:BAR:BAZ argle.py`.

If I add `FOO`, `BAR`, and `BAZ` to `$CLASSPATH` this works. I tried to add them to `sys.path` at run-time, but that doesn't appear to work for jars. It *does* work if I add a path to the expanded jars to `sys.path` at runtime. Is there a simple alternative to exploding the jar files? Augmenting `$CLASSPATH` for every user that runs this script is not an acceptable alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well! I looked at the jython startup script, but my bash isn't good enough to understand it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the `-D` option to set `python.path`:

```
jython -Dpython.path=FOO:BAR:BAZ argyle.py
```

Comment: NB: on Windows Replace colon ':' separator with semi-colon ';' separator. jython -Dpython.path=FOO;BAR;BAZ argyle.py

Comment: on Windows use the double backslash \\ when specifying paths, and if the path name contains spaces surround it with double quotes. Don't know if the trailing slash / is required. I get things work without it.

Answer (score 22):

`jython` command supports passing arguments through to the `java` command... So:

```
jython -J-cp JAR1:JAR2
```

You can verify the resulting command by adding `--print` switch:

```
jython -J-cp JAR1:JAR2 --print
```

The above will print out the actual java command instead of executing it.

Answer (score 7):

`java -cp JAR1:JAR2:jython.jar org.python.util.jython pythonScript.py` works here, both on Linux and Macintosh. On Windows, swap the colons in the classpaths for semicolons and you should be golden.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a big JAR which contains all related classes. The following ant snippet shows the idea:

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <unjar src="lib/jython.jar" dest="${classes.dir}" />
    <unjar src="lib/FOO.jar" dest="${classes.dir}" />
    <unjar src="lib/BAR.jar" dest="${classes.dir}" />
    <unjar src="lib/BAZ.jar" dest="${classes.dir}" />

    <jar destfile="build/jar/bigjython.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: Now how do I run my script using bigjython.jar?

Comment: The bigjython.jar was meant to include the original jython.jar plus your extra jars. So at the end the bigjython jar should work the same as jython.jar but without the need of the -cp parameter.

Comment: I'm not using jython.jar - I'm using `jython` command from the shell to execute argle.py