# Jython jmxmp protocol support

Tags: java, jython, jmx

I'm developing collection of monitoring script and templates for [zabbix](http://zabbix.com/). It's called [ZTC](https://bitbucket.org/rvs/ztc/) and all script are on python.

Now I want to add support for some java monitoring. I've not found the way to do it from CPython - only from java or jython. Since all project is on python, I've decided to write a simple script on jython, which would be called from my cpython classes.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jython

#Java Dependencies
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

#Python Dependencies
import sys, cmd, socket

def usage():
    print """Usage:
    jmxclient.py -h
    jmxclient.py <connect_url> <jmx_attribute_path> <jmx_property>"""

class JMXClient:
    remote = None

    def connect(self, connect_url):
        if self.remote:
            return True

        #Establish Connection to JMX Server
        url = javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL(connect_url);
        connector = javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
        self.remote = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

    def getAttribute(self, mbean_path, attribute):
        """Query the mbean server for a specific attribute and return the
        result"""
        obn =  javax.management.ObjectName(mbean_path);
        result = self.remote.getAttribute(obn, attribute);

        return result    

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

if sys.argv[1] in ('-h', '--help'):
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

if len(sys.argv) <> 4:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

(connect_url, mbean_path, attribute) = sys.argv[1:]

j = JMXClient()
j.connect(connect_url)
print j.getAttribute(mbean_path, attribute)
```

Ok, now I'm trying to get some attribute from terracotta server. It uses jmxmp with url service:jmx:jmxmp://0.0.0.0:9520.

So, I'm running my script as follows:

```
$ ./jmxclient.py service:jmx:jmxmp://localhost:9520 java.lang.ClassLoading LoadedClassCount
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "./jmxclient.py", line 87, in ?
  File "./jmxclient.py", line 61, in connect
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:327)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:247)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

java.net.MalformedURLException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: jmxmp

(line numbers not relevant due to some stripped comments)

How do I add support of this jmxmp protocol?

I've found that it seems it might be enabled by jmxremote_optional.jar. How do I add this jar to my jython (pref. not system-wide)?

**UPDATE**:

As suggested, I've added jmxremote_optional.jar and jmxremote.jar from `jmxremote-1_0_1-ri-bin-b58.zip` reference implementation: `jython -Djava.endorsed.dirs=. -Dpython.path=.../jmxremote_optional.jar:.../jmxremote.jar:.../jmissl.jar jmxclient.py service:jmx:jmxmp://localhost:9520 java.lang.ClassLoading LoadedClassCount`, but still getting the same error. I'm sure that jmxremote_optional.jar is in classpath, and code seems to be very similar to reference examples.

After reading api docs, I've tried following changes:

```
url = javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL('jmxmp', 'localhost', 9520);
connector = javax.management.remote.jmxmp.JMXMPConnector(url)
connector.connect()
self.remote = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

which leads me to another exception:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "../src/jmxclient.py", line 87, in ?
  File "../src/jmxclient.py", line 61, in connect
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.opt.security.AdminClient.connectionOpen(AdminClient.java:209)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.generic.ClientSynchroMessageConnectionImpl.connect(ClientSynchroMessageConnectionImpl.java:72)
        at javax.management.remote.generic.GenericConnector.connect(GenericConnector.java:177)
        at javax.management.remote.jmxmp.JMXMPConnector.connect(JMXMPConnector.java:119)
        at javax.management.remote.generic.GenericConnector.connect(GenericConnector.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: javax.management.remote.message.HandshakeBeginMessage
```

Jython version is 2.2 and I don't like to use later version, because this scripts is mostly being used on RHEL5 boxes, and they only have jython 2.2.1.

PS: marking question as answered, because I've decided to give up and use jmxterm or similar tool, which all seems to work with jmxmp by just adding -Djava.endosed.dirs=/path/to/dir_with_jmxremote_optional/.
But I'd still like to see jython solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Man,  I read that post about 7 times .....

Anyways, here's what I think is going on. The jmxmp protocol is not packaged in the standard J2SE runtime. See this [page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/overview/connectors.html#wp998561). To quote:

**Note** – If you want to use a JMXMP connector, download the JSR 160 Reference Implementation from http://java.sun.com/products/JavaManagement/download.html, and add the jmxremote_optional.jar file to your classpath. You will find examples of use of the JMXMP connectors in the JMX Remote API Tutorial included with the JSR 160 Reference Implementation.

I'm not that familiar with jython, but it looks like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537682/how-can-i-add-jars-to-the-classpath-when-i-invoke-jython-without-adding-them-to) should hook you up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've read examples and even modified & run them, it still does not work via jython :(. I think I'll use pure-java client, not jython one. But if have more suggestions, I'd be very thankfull. BTW, what's exactly wrong with my question, I'm not native speaker and not from java world and know my question is not perfect, just asking how could I improve it.

Comment: Sorry rvs, it was not a comment on how it was written, I just could not figure out where the error was coming from. You speak [or write] just fine.

Comment: Oh, than sorry me for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem. The solution is to use a different method of importing jar `jmxremote_optional.jar`. It's described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638390/9209536

This code works in Jython 2.7

```
def importJar(jarFile):
    from java.net import URL, URLClassLoader
    from java.lang import ClassLoader
    from java.io import File
    m = URLClassLoader.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", [URL])
    m.accessible = 1
    m.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), [File(jarFile).toURL()])

importJar("opendmk_jmxremote_optional_jar-1.0-b01-ea.jar")

from javax.management.remote import JMXServiceURL
from javax.management.remote import JMXConnector
from javax.management.remote import JMXConnectorFactory

jmx_url = JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:jmxmp://server:port/")
jmx_connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmx_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use a different stack like [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org) which exports JMX information via HTTP and JSON. There a already various client binding (Perl via [Jmx4Perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org), Javascript, Java) although no Python yet. But it shouldn't be hard to build one from scratch, the protocol is described in detail [here](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html).