# Can I use a Groovy class in a python (jython) script?

Tags: groovy, jython

I have some libraries written in Groovy. I'd like to know if I can use them in python (jython). (By using I mean importing and instantiating them like normal java classes)

First I thought I could since groovy compiles down to `.class` files but then I got this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
at org.python.core.SyspathJavaLoader.findClass(SyspathJavaLoader.java:128)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 40 more
```

I was getting this even after I put the groovy jars on the classpath.

This is the command I am running:

```
jython -Dpython.path=<absolute path to groovy compiled classfiles>:<user home>.gradle/caches:<user home>.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib test.py
```

(where current groovy version is `2.5.7`)

test.py

```
from my.library.api import AGroovyClass
print("working")
```

In this particular case I just wanted to make sure I can at least import it. 
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Which groovy jars did you put on the classpath?

Comment: @tim_yates I guess I lied. I put the jars on python.path based on this article: https://wiki.python.org/jython/LearningJython#classpath-and-python-path and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537682/how-can-i-add-jars-to-the-classpath-when-i-invoke-jython-without-adding-them-t

Comment: The jars will need to be on the classpath, so the JVM running jython can find them

Comment: @tim_yates makes sense. Will give it a try and report back.